# Can I use ViewPager inside custom InfoWindowAdapter?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-adapter

I'm using a `InfoWindowAdapter` within Google Maps API2. My XML layout has some simple `TextView` and `ImageView` views, but I also need a ViewPager to allow the users to swipe a series of custom layouts associated with the marker on the map (an image and some text). My InfoWindow layout is:

spot_window_complex.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/my_relative_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/transparent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lin1"
    android:layout_width="275.0dip"
    android:layout_height="140.0dip"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="275.0dip"
        android:layout_height="85.0dip"
        android:background="@drawable/round" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="275.0dip"
        android:layout_height="40.0dip"
        android:background="#ffeeeeee"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="10.0dip"
        android:paddingTop="10.0dip">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10.0dip"
            android:paddingRight="3.0dip"
            android:src="@drawable/clock" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgThumbsUp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffeeeeee"
            android:paddingRight="3.0dip"
            android:src="@drawable/thumbsup" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPve"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="50.0dip"
            android:textColor="#ff29c200"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgThumbsDown"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffeeeeee"
            android:paddingRight="3.0dip"
            android:src="@drawable/thumbsdown" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtNve"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffc91c11"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I've created a simple XML layout to try to get the ViewPager working within the `InfoWindowAdapter`:

viewpager_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:padding="10dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/countrylabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Country: " />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/country"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/countrylabel" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My ViewPagerAdapter seems pretty standard:

```
class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    String[] country = new String[]{"China", "India", "United States","Indonesia",
            "Brazil", "Pakistan", "Nigeria", "Bangladesh", "Russia", "Japan"};

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return country.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container,
                false);

        TextView txtcountry = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country);
        txtcountry.setText(country[position]);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);
        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        // Remove viewpager_item.xml from ViewPager
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);
    }
}
```

And my `InfoWindowAdapter` seems OK too:

```
public class SimpleInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {
    public SimpleInfoWindowAdapter() {
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        View v;
        MySimpleMarker myMarker = mSimpleMarkersHashMap.get(marker);

        v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.spot_window_complex, null);
        TextView txtPve = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtPve);
        TextView txtNve = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtNve);
        txtPve.setText("0"); //test string only
        txtNve.setText("0"); //test string only

        ViewPager vPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        vPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter());

        return v;
    }
}
```

The `TextView` and `ImageView` views that are static from the XML or are set by the adapter work fine, as does the general layout. However, my ViewPager, which should in this test case have 10 swipeable countries in `TextViews`, is blank. All the relevant code is being handled inside one fragment and there are no errors in the Android Monitor.
[image: Blank ViewPager above static content]

Any ideas what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I also need a ViewPager to allow the users to swipe a series of custom layouts associated with the marker on the map

That is not possible.

> Any ideas what I've done wrong?

The `View` you return from your `InfoWindowAdapter` is converted immediately into a `Bitmap`. That `Bitmap` is what winds up being rendered on the screen. Hence, you cannot have interactive widgets, like a `ViewPager`. Not only will they not be interactive, but anything that is rendered asynchronously (e.g., pages in a `ViewPager`) might not be rendered in time before the `Bitmap` is created.

Or, quoting [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows#custom_info_windows):

> Note: The info window that is drawn is not a live view. The view is rendered as an image (using View.draw(Canvas)) at the time it is returned. This means that any subsequent changes to the view will not be reflected by the info window on the map. To update the info window later (for example, after an image has loaded), call showInfoWindow(). Furthermore, the info window will not respect any of the interactivity typical for a normal view such as touch or gesture events. However you can listen to a generic click event on the whole info window as described in the section below.

Comment: OK, thanks. Follow-up question is that I'm trying to recreate something that's showing the same behaviour I want. This App (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.HurryHereNow.HHN&hl=en_GB, example image 2, or if install then focus on Cambridge, UK) shows an InfoWindow with a swipeable and changing view pager (or similar) portion. How do you think they might have coded that? It def works, as I'm using the live version now, with swipe and onClickListener capabilities!

Comment: @iaindownie: If it is interactive, it is not an info window. Presumably, they have a `View` at the desired coordinates. Use **`uiautomatorviewer`** to see what their view hierarchy is.

Comment: Thanks - that's been really helpful. If you can/want to edit your answer to suggest replacing the InfoWindow etc. with a custom view (as identified by **uiautomatorviewer**), then I'll accept the answer gladly and hope it's of use to more than just me!